# c fscanf storing strings

Tags: c, string, scanf

I am using fscanf to read in a file with this format per line:

```
//FEATURE_ID|FEATURE_NAME|FEATURE_CLASS|STATE_ALPHA|STATE_NUMERIC|COUNTY_NAME|COUNTY_NUMERIC|PRIMARY_LAT_DMS|PRIM_LONG_DMS|PRIM_LAT_DEC|PRIM_LONG_DEC|SOURCE_LAT_DMS|SOURCE_LONG_DMS|SOURCE_LAT_DEC|SOURCE_LONG_DEC|ELEV_IN_M|ELEV_IN_FT|MAP_NAME|DATE_CREATED|DATE_EDITED
```

Here is the first line of the file, for example:

```
//913064|Oso Spring|Spring|NM|35|Rio Arriba|039|365418N|1061159W|36.904945|-106.1998199|||||2863|9393|Bighorn Peak|12/01/1991|04/19/2011
```

My code is this:

```
int id, state_num, county_num, elev_m, elev_f;
float lat_dec, lon_dec;
char* name[25];
char* class[25];
char* state[25];
char* county[25];
char* lat[25];
char* lon[25];
char* s_lat_dms[25];
char* s_lon_dms[25];
char* s_lat_dec[25];
char* s_lon_dec[25];
char* map_name[25];
char* date_created[25];
char* date_edited[25];

fscanf(data, "%d|%[^|]s|%s|%s|%d|%s|%d|%s|%s|%f|%f|%s|%s|%s|%s|%d|%d|%s|%s|%s", &id, name,
class, state, &state_num, county, &county_num, lat, lon, &lat_dec,
           &lon_dec, s_lat_dms, s_lon_dms, s_lat_dec, s_lon_dec, &elev_m, &elev_f, map_name,
date_created, date_edited);
    printf("id:%d \nname:%s \nclass:%s \nstate:%s \nstate_num:%d \n", id, name, class, state,
state_num);
```

But when i run it on the command line it prints out this:

id:913064

name:Oso Spring

class:�&6+�

state:

state_num:1178

Why is it not properly storing data in the class char* array?
There are some specific bits of the code that need to be kept, like the first string value needs to be able to keep the whitespace, so I added the "[^|]", but once I did this it started inputting nonsense characters in class. I have looked extensively into fscanf but cannot find how to correctly do what I am trying to do. Could someone help me organize this properly, and fill the knowledge hole I cannot seem to fill?

Comment: Shouldn't `char* name[25];` be `char name[25];` etc? Make sure you restrict the input length too, with `%25s`. Note too that `Bighorn Peak` scanned by `%s` will stop at the space, leaving `Peak` to be scanned by the next format specifier.

Comment: You didn't ask for an alternate way to do this, but reading a full line at a time into a large buffer, then using `strtok()` to break the string apart on the `'|'` delimiter character is likely to be a bit less maddening than anything having to do with `scanf`

Comment: Using `strtok` is a well-used way of processing data such as comma or tab delimited text, but it has the drawback that consecutive delimiters such as your `|||||` are treated as a *single* delimiter, rather than leaving "empty" data fields. If you have `strsep` that will treat each `|` individually.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, of course, though I contend that even wrong answers from strtok is still an improvement over scanf :-)

Comment: @SteveFriedl I agree: I have never liked using `scanf` family to filter out any delimiter except whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no format specifier `%[...]s`. There's only `%[...]`. Drop the `s`, as it causes the [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function to look for a literal `s` in the input.

And as mentioned you have arrays of pointers, not arrays of characters. That means e.g. `state` as argument will decay to a pointer to its first element, which in turn is a pointer, and it will have the type `char **` which is incorrect for both the `%[` and the `%s` formats.

The array of pointer issue will also lead to problem when calling `printf`.

A good compiler would warn about the mismatching type and format specifier. If yours don't then try to enable more warnings (using e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` with GCC or Clang).